# Polchinski OPE of spacetime translation current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I am trying to derive
$$
j^\mu(z):e^{ik\cdot X(0,0)}: \;\sim \frac{k^\mu}{2z}:e^{ik\cdot X(0,0)} \tag{2.3.14a}
$$
from Polchinski's String Theory vol.1 equation (2.3.14a).
using $j^{\mu}=\frac{i}{\alpha}\partial_aX^\mu$.

My attempt:

$$
j^\mu(z):e^{ik\cdot X(0,0)}:  \; =\frac{i}{\alpha'}\partial_a X^\mu(z):\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{i^n}{n!}\left(k\cdot X(0,0)\right)^n:
$$

Now the first term of the summation can be ignored since its non-singular, then we get
$$
= \frac{i}{\alpha'}\partial_a X^\mu :i k^\nu X_\nu(0,0)\left(1+\frac{i}{2}(k\cdot X(0,0))+\frac{i^2}{3!}(k\cdot X(0,0))^2+\ldots\right):
$$
I know that the contraction will give a $1/z$ term but my problem is with re-expressing the exponential. I don't quite get how the series is again the same exponential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
j(z) : e^{ i k X } : &= \frac{i}{\alpha'} \partial X(z) \sum_{n=0}^n \frac{ : ( i k X )^n : }{ n! } \\
&=  \frac{i}{\alpha'} \sum_{n=0}^n \frac{  ( i k)^n }{ n! } \partial X(z)  : X^n : \\
&\sim  \frac{i}{\alpha'} \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{  ( i k)^n  }{ n! } n : X^{n-1} : \partial_z X(z) X(0,0) \\
&\sim  \frac{i}{\alpha'} \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{  ( i k)^n  }{ n! } n : X^{n-1} : \partial_z [ - \frac{\alpha'}{2} \log |z|^2 ] \\
&\sim \frac{k}{2z}  \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{ : ( i k X )^{n-1} : }{ (n-1) ! } \\
&\sim \frac{k}{2z} : e^{ i k X } :  
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what happens from line 2 to 3?

Comment: I contracted the fields in the usual way. For instance $X_1 : X_2 X_3 X_4 : ~=~ (X_1 X_2) :X_3 X_4: + ( X_1 X_3 ):X_2 X_4: + ( X_1 X_4 ) : X_2 X_3 : + : X_1 X_2 X_3 X_4 :$. I'm using ( ) to denote contraction. This property only holds for (generalized) free fields.